# please help me in finding all the counts of beautiful permutation

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming, permutation, stdvector, unordered-map

With an array consisting of integers where each integer occurs at most 2 times in the array, I have to count the number of beautiful permutations.

A permutation is beautiful if there is no index *i* such that P<sub>i</sub> = P<sub>i+1</sub> where *i* belongs to [0, n-1).

```
struct hashFunction
{
    size_t operator()(const vector<int>& myVector) const
    {
        std::hash<int> hasher;
        size_t answer = 0;
        for (int i : myVector)
        {
            answer ^= hasher(i) + 0x9e3779b9 +
                (answer << 6) + (answer >> 2);
        }
        return answer;
    }
};

bool beautiful(vector<int>& ds)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ds.size(); i++)
    {
        if (ds[i] == ds[i + 1])
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

void permutation(vector<int>& arr, int index,
    unordered_set<vector<int>, hashFunction>& unorderedsetOfVectors)
{
    if (unorderedsetOfVectors.find(arr) != unorderedsetOfVectors.end()) return;
    if (index == arr.size())
    {
        if (beautiful(arr) == true)
        {
            unorderedsetOfVectors.insert(arr);
            return;
        }
    }

    for (int i = index; i < arr.size(); i++)
    {
        swap(arr[index], arr[i]);
        permutation(arr, index + 1, unorderedsetOfVectors);
        swap(arr[index], arr[i]);
    }
}

int permutations(vector<int> arr)
{
    unordered_set<vector<int>, hashFunction> unorderedsetOfVectors;
    permutation(arr, 0, unorderedsetOfVectors);
    return unorderedsetOfVectors.size() % 1000000007;
}
```

How can I optimize this code?

Comment: I haven't read your `permutation` in detail, but you may have a look at [std::next_permutation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation)

Comment: First sort your input so that you can generate permutations in a fixed order without duplicates (strictly speaking you only need to group each pair together). And during generation you can check for beautiful too so you don't produce any ugly permutations. Then it's simply counting. The unordered set wastes huge amounts of time and memory. Even better would be working out a forumla for the number of permutations.